# Download File Types Confusion - application/octet-stream

Tags: php, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, download

I'm using this code:

```
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // some day in the past
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$original);
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
readfile('/tmp/'.$original);
```

to output files from my server (EC2) which have been grabbed off S3. This works fine for images and .txt files but PDF and .doc seem to be damaged in some way. They won't open, or if they do the content is garbled.

I'm thinking it must be to do with the content type application/octet-stream? However my knowledge is limited in this area - I've done some reading and trial and error, but I'm no further forward with it.

In S3 the content types are set for all files as application/octet-stream. I'm not sure if this is right either (it's not something I've set when uploading the files)

Any ideas appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: File types that download without error are jpeg, txt and rtf. I get errors with doc and pdf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for .doc files you should set **application/msword**, for .pdf files you should set **application/pdf**

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/pdf'); // set content type
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.pdf"'); // force download
readfile('original.pdf'); // read the content to server
?>
```

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php